# Javascript Jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I want the div to slide on the screen left to right i have a html file and a java script file shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>DY Fitness</title>
          <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="javascript" src="css/nav.js"></script>
        </head>
            <style>
             @import "css/nav.css";
            </style>
     </head>
     <body>
        <input type="button" id="left" value="Left"/>
        <input type="button" id="right" value="Right"/>
        <div id="content">Move</div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

<------------------ Javascript(nav.js)-------------------------->

```
$("#right").click(function() {
    $("#content").animate(
            {"left": "+=50px"},
            "slow");
});
$("#left").click(function() {
    $("#content").animate(
            {"left": "-=50px"},
            "slow");
});
```

ithink the code is correct but its not working for me any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: forgot to wrap code in `ready` handler. Also can't have 2 `<head>` in page

Comment: "its not working for me": you'll need to expand on this.

Comment: What about is "not working". Do you get errors in console? You need to do a bit of digging before posting "code doesn't work" as that is a very broad term. Lookup how to debug JS in your browser of choice and start there.

Comment: "its not working for me" as in its not working when i click the button "right"

Comment: what's content of nav.js ?

Comment: the div just stays where it is

Comment: also im new to Jquery and js how do i do the ready tags thanks

Comment: content of nav.js is posted above

Answer (score 1):

set `position:absolute;` to content, see code working: http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/mnjxmfhr/ :

```
#content{
    position:absolute;
    /* ---- */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to help you because you don't give us that much clue. For exemple, what the console output ?

Anyway, by putting your script tag in the `head` you have to assume that the script will be loaded before the DOM has finished to be loaded. So your script can't find #right or #left element because they haven't been loaded in the DOM three.

You have 2 solutions :

#### First one :

Wrap your code in a load event like this :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //Your code here
});
```

or the shortcut :

```
$(function() {
    //Your code here
});
```

#### Second one :

Put your script tag before the end of the body

```
   <script type="javascript" src="css/nav.js"></script>
</body>
```

Also note that you can't have 2 `<head>` into another one.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot attach click handlers to elements that have not yet been loaded to the DOM. There for you should wrap all event handler assignments in the $(document).ready function or $(window).load function. The first fires when the DOM is completely loaded. The second fires when all images and other resources have also loaded.

The first is:

```
$(document).ready({
    .... code goes here ....
});
```

or you can use the shortcut for it:

```
$(function(){
    .... code goes here ....
});
```

The second is:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    .... code goes here ....
});
```

The window.load method is primarily used when getting the size of objects that might include images, since the size of a div will be misreported when getting its size before the image is completely loaded.

Try this and see if it helps:

```
$(function(){
    $("#right").click(function() {
        $("#content").animate(
                {"left": "+=50px"},
                "slow");
    });
    $("#left").click(function() {
        $("#content").animate(
                {"left": "-=50px"},
                "slow");
    });
});
```

IMPORTANT: Your #content element must be set to position: relative; in your css or this will not work.  see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8gog742m/